# Generic ant rules script as an alternative to using Maven

Tags: ant

Android has an ant script file with generic targets for compile, clean, etc.

Are there any open source ant scripts that define standard targets such as these for general java projects?

I don't want to bother installing and using maven, but I also don't want to bother creating and maintaining ant scripts for each project.

Comment: You can find some of these kind of ANT scripts at [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/antbuildscript/?source=dlp) site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are new to both Maven and Ant. If I'm wrong you can ignore the rest of this post :)

I don't know of any generic open source Ant files. I've never had the need to look for one. I think its well worth the effort to learn Ant and create your own generic script. Ant is easy to learn and it is a very flexible, powerful and reliable build tool. You'll find it quite easy to create a build file that you can reuse over and over again on different projects.

With regards to having to maintain Ant scripts, its a bit of a fallacy. You'll find that once you've got a script that works in a generic way you'll hardly ever have to touch it again except when you need to do things in a custom way (usually around packaging and deployment). When that happens, you'll be glad you're using a tool like Ant that gives you the flexibility to do what you want to be able to do without getting in your way.